# Force all iterations on an iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iteration

I've written a for-loop using map, with a function that has a side-effect. Here's a minimal working example of what I mean:

```
def someFunc(t):
    n, d = t
    d[n] = str(n)

def main():
    d = {}
    map(somefunc, ((i,d) for i in range(10**3)))
    print(len(d))
```

So it's clear that `someFunc`, which is mapped onto the non-negative numbers under 1000, has the side-effect of populating a dictionary, which is later used for something else.

Now, given the way that the above code has been structured, the expected output of `print(len(d))` is `0`, since `map` returns an iterator, and not a list (unlike python2.x). So if I really want to see the changes applied to `d`, then I would have to iterate over that map object until completion. One way I could do so is:

```
d = {}
for i in map(somefunc, ((i,d) for i in range(10**3))):
    pass
```

But that doesn't seem very elegant. I could call `list` on the map object, but that would require O(n) memory, which is inefficient. Is there a way to force a full iteration over the map object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do this (run a `map()` just for the side effects), but there is a [`itertools` `consume` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that applies here:

```
from collections import deque

deque(map(somefunc, ((i,d) for i in range(10**3))), maxlen=0)
```

The [`collections.deque()` object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), configured to a maximum size of 0, consumes the `map()` iterable with no additional memory use. The `deque` object is [specifically optimized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b4b892e0962a7050c5064133c59955691f9776c/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L366-L379) for this use-case.