# map doesn't work as expected in python 3

Tags: python, functional-programming

Newbie here.

This code worked in python 2.7, but does not in 3.3

```
def extractFromZipFiles(zipFiles, files, toPath):
    extractFunction = lambda fileName:zipFiles.extract(fileName, toPath) 
    map (extractFunction,files)
    return
```

No error but the files are not extracted. However when I replace with for loop works fine.

```
def extractFromZipFiles(zipFiles, files, toPath):
    for fn in files:
        zipFiles.extract(fn, toPath)
#     extractFunction = lambda fileName:zipFiles.extract(fileName, toPath) 
#     map (extractFunction,files)
    return
```

Code doesn't error.

Comment: Because it is just a generator

Comment: Honestly, just use the `for` loop. It's *way* more explicit to the casual passer-by what the heck you're actually doing.

Comment: In Python2, that map call is creating a list of `None`s which is pointless and is discouraged. The for loop is much cleaner. I'm not sure why people have a hard time writing two good lines of code when one crappy one will do.

Comment: @gnibbler, there's a pretty broad misconception that "pythonic" means "really short one-liner". While they can *often* overlap, it's obvious in cases like this that they don't *always*

Comment: obviously you already know that, but i'm just guessing that's why others have a hard time of it

Comment: @mhlester, Yes, and teaching this (and other good habits) to others is an important function of websites like these.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is generally discouraged to use map to call functions, but that being said, the reason it doesn't work is because Python 3 returns a generator, not a list, so the function isn't called until you've iterated on it. To ensure that it calls the functions:

```
list(map(extractFunction,files))
```

But it's creating an unused list. The better approach is to be more explicit:

```
for file in files:
    extractFunction(file)
```

As is the case with heads, two lines can indeed be better than one.

Answer (score 0):

`map` in python3 is an iterator, whereas in python2, it computed a list. So, what you're looking for, is [a way to consume the entire iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21210633/198633). Thankfully, there's [an `itertools` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for this:

```
import collections
def extractFromZipFiles(zipFiles, files, toPath):
    extractFunction = lambda fileName:zipFiles.extract(fileName, toPath) 
    collections.deque(map(extractFunction,files), maxlen=0)
    return
```

Comment: I agree with @mhlester. Granted, your answer is correct, but this approach is just plain awful.

Comment: I was simply trying to solve OP's problem with minimal edits. Then again, I /am/ crazy enough to write some pretty unreadable code when I haz teh tunnel vision

Comment: It *is* an interesting approach. I had to go back and re-read the question to make sure this wasn't one of your homework-obfuscation answers

Comment: @mhlester: if you have to think about it, it's not homework obfuscation. I try to make it overly obvious for those applications

Comment: using `map` or list comprehensions etc. for sideeffects is poor practice. This just buries bad code under another layer of complication.